# Manually set width of spinner dropdown list in android

Tags: android, layout, spinner

Is it possible to set the width of a spinner dropdown list in code? I have a spinner populated with integers, and it does not look good with the list expanding to full width. Can I set the width to wrap the content somehow?

```
Spinner hSpinner = (Spinner) timerView.findViewById(R.id.timer_hour_spinner);
ArrayList<Integer> hList = new ArrayList<Integer>(21);

for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) { hList.add(i); }

ArrayAdapter hAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(RemindMe.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, hList);
hAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

hSpinner.setAdapter(hAdapter);
```

Thanks!

Linus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the width of anything in code by adjusting its `LayoutParams`. The details of that varies by container (`LinearLayout` vs. `RelativeLayout` vs. ...).

However, I'm confused why you want to change the width "in code". Why not just set the width to be `wrap_content` in the layout XML?

Comment: I have set the width of the spinner to "wrap_content" in the layout file, but when I click on the spinner in the app the dropdown list expands to full width. That's why I figured it had to be resized in code if possible. I might have been unclear in my question, but it is the dropdown list that I want to set the width on, not the spinner object itself. Any ideas? And as always, thanks for helping!

Comment: Ah, sorry, misunderstood. You could try a different layout for the drop-down view. I don't know if the width is being defined by the drop-down layout or is intrinsic to the dialog that is the "drop-down". If it is the latter, there probably is nothing you can do.

Comment: OK, I figured it would be messy if at all possible. I actually skipped the spinner and went for a SeekBar instead. Looks good, so it worked out anyway! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
setDropDownWidth(desiredWidth);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is straightforward to control the spinner dropdown appearance.  Try this:

```
//Step 1. create the drop down list
static List<String> special_Spinner_Display_List = new ArrayList<String>();  
// add your values to the list...(this is best done using a for loop)
special_Spinner_Display_List.add(item1);
special_Spinner_Display_List.add(item2);  //etc., etc.

//Step 2. build the spinner
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter_special = new ArrayAdapter(this, 
      R.layout.your_special_spinner, special_Spinner_Display_List);
arrayAdapter_special.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.special_spinner_dropdown);
specialSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter_special);

//Step 3. create an XML layout file called special_spinner_dropdown where you can 
//style to your heart's content.  Here's an example:

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/SpinnerDropdown"
style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:background="#D5ECED"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textSize="24sp" 
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

That's it.  Lemme know how it works!

Comment: do you know how to set the width of the drop down resource? it doesnt seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Set dropdown width in xml file of spinner using the tag

android:dropDownWidth="@dimen/desired_width"

Explaination :

```
mDropDownWidth = pa.getLayoutDimension(R.styleable.Spinner_dropDownWidth,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

this field is used for dropdown width when spinner item is initialized in Spinner class

for programatically changing spinner dropdown width above api level 16, use

```
mSpinner.setDropDownWidth(size_in_pixel);
```